# Jade locals undefined with Express.js

Tags: express, pug

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.xxx = 'aaaa';
    next();
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

In Jade:

```
meta(name='csrf-token', content='#{xxx}')
```

content is undefined.

And there is a long list of `app.use('/xxx/xxx', ...)`. Do I have to pass locals in these routers? Or where is it not working here?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes and parantheses:

```
meta(name='csrf-token', content=xxx)
```

This works for me